# How to access resource bundle parameter using variable?

Tags: jasper-reports, bundle

Is it possible to have something like the following?

```
$R{${P{my_paramater}}
```

The above throws a complilation error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That won't work, you'll have to do `str($P{my_paramater})`.