# Use parameter to get string from resource bundle

Tags: jasper-reports, resourcebundle

Is it possible to use parameter while getting string from resource bundle in JasperReports? I mean: `$R{$P{reportName}}` **reportName** dynamically changed from server side.

If it is not possible, how can I change it dynamically?

Thx all.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22457632/jasper-report-5-2-resource-bundle-parameter-using-variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jasper Report 5.2: Resource bundle parameter using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22457632/jasper-report-5-2-resource-bundle-parameter-using-variable)

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is not possible to nest those type of objects together. In fact an error occurs. Here is a similar question with some workarounds : [Using dynamic resource key](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/537521/using-dynamic-resource-key-name)